# How to make an executable JAR files

Tags: netbeans

How do you build an executable JAR file in Netbeans 12.6?  I realize this question is asked frequently but none of the other solutions previously posted here work on the latest version of Netbeans. All I ever get is "no main manifest attribute".  Amazing to me that such a simple thing does not just work out-of-the-box. Getting Netbeans set up has been harder to learn than Java itself!

Comment: Explain in detail what you have attempted so that others can attempt to reproduce your issue. Also, consider the possibility that NetBeans isn't necessarily the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> When you set the project’s main class, you ensure that the main class is be designated in the manifest. To set the project’s main class:
>
> 1. Right-click the project’s node and choose Properties.
> 2. Select the Run category and enter `projectname.className` in the Main Class field.
> 3. Click OK to close the Project Properties dialog box.

https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy.html

Comment: Does not work on version 12.6.   I know this used to work on earlier versions.  Thanks for the fast response but still "no main manifest attribute" when run at command prompt.  Also, no "dist" folder is made, even on "release-profile".  Read something about needing to do some custom coding in the "POM" file.   Maybe this is a Maven problem?  Ant seems to work but Maven and Gradle are no-go for this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. For Maven, you need to update the POM.xml file. Netbeans does not work out of the box in version 12.6 like older versions. I'm sure they added more functionality but it no longer just works.  It maybe similar for Gradle. Add this above  ~ < /project> in your file.  Change your class name to your's. (My class was called main).

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```